# Does creating an AMI on AWS require the reboot of the original machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When creating an AMI image from an existing EC2 instance, does it require the restart of the existing instance?

I make a copy of the instance, and subsequently the server went down because it turned off a process monitor which led to downtime, but I can't remember if it was because I rebooted the system (I can't remember if I rebooted it), or if it was because I made a copy of the image.

[image]

Comment: posted a solution with docs as to what was says about reboot and for you question yes it does stop your instance for the duration it is creating that ami.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's option to enable `No reboot` during create AMI

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. I did see that option, but I didn't understand what it meant. I was unsure if it meant enable reboot of target image, not source instance. So to confirm, this means do not reboot source instance? Thank you!!

Comment: You need to stick on that if you don't want to reboot the EC2 when creating AMI because it will take more time if the EC2 alive when creating AMI.

Comment: Hi @vumdao, Thank you for your great answer. I have a concern that for best practice, we need to uncheck in order to "maintain the file system integrity", right?

Answer (score 4):

> When creating an AMI image from an existing EC2 instance, does it require the restart of the existing instance

to answer this yes, when ami is being created aws the instance for ensuring data integrity.
[doc says this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#process-creating-an-ami-ebs) "*Amazon EC2 powers down the instance before creating the AMI to ensure that everything on the instance is stopped and in a consistent state during the creation process*."

you can override this behaviour by enabling **no reboot**  while creating ami.

> No reboot – This option is not selected by default. Amazon EC2 shuts down the instance, takes snapshots of any attached volumes, creates and registers the AMI, and then reboots the instance. Select No reboot to avoid having your instance shut down.

refer 6 point of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html.

also whenever you are unsure about anything just follow the docs of that service, it will be define in one way or the another.